# Comment on deleting/deleted answers

Tags: support, comments

Just a little technical matter, if I:

1. add to an answer of mine a comment sent to another user and *then* I delete my answer

or

2. put the same
   kind of comment on a *deleted* answer of mine

do the other user receive the alert and can he/she see my comment?

Comment: 1) Sometimes I comment on answers of new users that are "not an answer" and, if I recall correctly, I do receive notifications if they comment and the answer is then deleted; 2) Can you comment on an already-deleted post? These are "semi-locked", although you can edit them, but also only by the OP.

Comment: Thank you @Werner! My curiosity comes from a case of type 1): I had commented an answer of mine and then deleted it. On 2) you are right: comments are disabled on deleted/locked posts (even if they are my own posts), I haven't noted that!

Comment: Reference: [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668/168244) The link references deletion by a mod, not the OP, so I'm not exactly sure. My guess is one could collaborate with another user and post content to [Formatting Sand-Box](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/208/5764).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer seems to be "yes, but..." based on [Can I get more information on an inbox notification for a comment on a deleted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180013/can-i-get-more-information-on-an-inbox-notification-for-a-comment-on-a-deleted-a). The notification will persist, but you'll only get to see as much of the comment as the inbox shows (until you reach 10k rep).